# Pandas - Min and Max function

Tags: python, pandas, max, min

I am playing with the min and max functions in python

I'm wondering if there's a way to get a unique list of items and then print the min and max values of each column

example:

| Month | T-shirt Sales | Hat Sales | short Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 757 | 200 | 696 |
| Feb | 500 | 359 | 855 |
| Mar | 685 | 252 | 100 |
| Jan | 885 | 598 | 266 |
| Feb | 1001 | 223 | 1000 |
| Mar | 882 | 298 | 754 |

What I'd like to do here is find the min and max sales per month for each category

**Desired Output**

| Month | Max TS Sales | Min TS Sales | Max Hat Sales | Min Hat Sales | Max Short Sales | Min short Sales |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Jan | 885 | 757 | 598 | 598 | 696 | 266 |
| Feb | 1001 | 500 | 223 | 359 | 1000 | 855 |
| Mar | 882 | 685 | 298 | 252 | 754 | 100 |

Is there a simple way to do this or is it a case that I'll have to get the min and max for each column separately and append to a DF?

Thanks

Comment: `df.groupby('Month').agg(['min','max'])`.

Comment: @QuangHoang simple but efficient, great thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'month': ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Jan', 'Feb'],
                   't-shirt': [1, 2, 3, 4],
                   'hat': [4, 3, 2, 1]})

res = df.groupby(by='month').agg(['min', 'max'])
```